# Interpretation of "ゴミとして引き取ってもらった"

Tags: reading-comprehension, subsidiary-verbs, giving-and-receiving

> まあ、新居で邪魔になりそうなものはゴミとして引き取ってもらったけど。

An internal remark from a couple moving into a new place.

well, 新居で邪魔になりそうなもの -> the people visiting new place, aka me/us

ゴミとして -> me/us as garbage

引き取ってもらったけど -> ?? , we're receiving care from ...? (the new place?).

We, the new inhabitants of this property, are gratefully being taken care of as garbage (???)

probably not right haha, they did move some boxes from the old place and that could also be the new visitors/garbage (?)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/260/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54623/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54631/9831

Comment: i'm aware of that, more concerned about what the idea of ゴミとして引き取って is in this case, and why that would be a てもらう situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your difficulties stem from the fact that

> 新居で邪魔になりそうなもの

is not:

> the people visiting new place, aka me/us

it's:

> things that seemed like they would get in the way at our new place

Then, it becomes perfectly normal for

> ゴミとして引き取ってもらった

To mean:

> had (these things) handled/taken away/collected as garbage.

I'm unsure how/why you are interpreting `新居で邪魔になりそうなもの` to refer to the couple moving into this new place, but the definitions for [邪魔](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%82%AA%E9%AD%94) and [物](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%89%A9) might help.

The whole sentence is something like:

> (We) had the things that seemed like they'd get in the way at (our) new place collected as garbage.